# MYSQL GROUP and ORDER for messaging system

Tags: mysql, messaging

I've been pulling my hair with this one, I have a messaging system for a website where users can message each other, the inbox right now will show you a list of messages (like old school text messages) but i want to make it more modern and give it a more Facebook like feel.
The Table is very basic

```
id  senderid    recipientid dateadded   message
--------------------------------------------------------------------
1   1              2        2013-04-01  hello1
2   3              2        2013-04-02  hello2
3   1              2        2013-04-03  hello3
4   3              2        2013-04-04  hello4
5   3              2        2013-04-05  hello5
6   4              2        2013-04-06  hello6
```

Now, what I'm having a hard time with is loading the messages, grouping them by the senderid with the newest dateadded  with the messages from that sender ordered oldest to newest

So I would like the table above to load like this

```
id  senderid    recipientid dateadded   message
--------------------------------------------------------------------
5   3              2        2013-04-05  hello5
4   3              2        2013-04-04  hello4
2   3              2        2013-04-02  hello2
3   1              2        2013-04-03  hello2
1   1              2        2013-04-01  hello1
6   4              2        2013-04-01  hello1
```

The senderid with the newest message first and so on.

Here's the query I was just using based on other similar posts

```
SELECT m.*
FROM messages m 
INNER JOIN (
SELECT senderid, recipientid, dateadded
FROM messages
WHERE recipientid = :user_id
GROUP BY senderid
ORDER BY dateadded DESC
) senders ON m.senderid = senders.senderid
ORDER BY senders.dateadded DESC
```

Unfortunately that query just doesn't work it only groups the senderid's

Again the goal here is to load all message sent to the logged in user but order them by the senderid and the newest dateadded for the messages

Thank you in advance for any comments, Stackoverflow has helped me immensely and I really appreciate all the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this one?

```
SELECT senderid, recipientid, MAX(dateadded) AS MAX_dateadded
FROM messages
WHERE recipientid = :user_id
GROUP BY senderid
ORDER BY MAX_dateadded DESC
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, this query did not work, it just showed me the unique senderid with their latest message, my goal is to load all the messages for each sender to that recipient separated into threads

Comment: Oh! Now I've got your initial idea! `SELECT m.*
FROM messages m 
INNER JOIN (
SELECT senderid, recipientid, MAX(dateadded) AS MAX_dateadded
FROM messages
WHERE recipientid = :user_id
GROUP BY senderid
ORDER BY MAX_dateadded DESC
) senders ON m.senderid = senders.senderid
ORDER BY senders.MAX_dateadded DESC, m.senderid, m.dateadded DESC`

Comment: Well that did it! that work great, thank you so much, any chance you can give me a quick explanation on how the query works, i'm going to be staring at it until I can digest it but it would be nice to have a quick idea on how you came up with it. Thank you again I really appreciate you taking the time to answer!!!!

Comment: now if i could only figure out how to mark that your second query answered my question that'd be great, for now i checked the first query